# Are subqueries supported in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph Platform 2.6.4 and I want to call a subquery within a query. For example:

```
UNWIND [0, 1, 2] AS n
CALL {
  RETURN 'hi' AS returnValue
}
RETURN returnValue
```

I couldn't find anything like that in Memgraph documentation, but saw it in [Cypher best practices blog post](https://discord.com/channels/842007348272169002/890969003374289016/1067355614596038718). Is there a way to run subqueries in Memgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Memgraph doesn't support subqueries, but if you have a particular query maybe you can rewrite it using other constructs, or you can implement a custom query module. Here is a [how-to guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/how-to-guides/create-a-new-module-python) on implementing a custom query module in Python, although you can do it in C/C++, Rust, or any other programming language that can be compiled to a shared object library.